# Stripe: How to attach a debit-card for payouts

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I spent the last two days pouring over the stripe documentation, but can't I find how to add a card to an "**account**" in stripe.

Q. How to attach a debit-card for payouts to `stripe.accounts.create`?

```js
stripe.accounts.create({
    type: 'standard',
    business_type: 'individual',
    default_currency:'USD',
    country: 'US',
    email: 'bob@example.com',
    requested_capabilities: [ 'transfers' ],

    // here ?

}).then(acc => {

    // or maybe ?

}).catch(console.error)
```

Also, an example on how to select that payment method to payout to would be appreciated.

Thanks for any input

Comment: You would tokenize a debit card using Stripe.js and Elements [0], then attach it to the Connect account as an external account: https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_cards/create

[0] https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With in your `counts.create()` fn, add an attribute "external_account"

e.g.

```js
    stripe.accounts.create({
       country: 'US',
       default_currency:'USD',
       external_account:card_token,
       type: 'custom',
       requested_capabilities: ['card_payments', 'transfers'],
     })
    .then(acc => {
```

Note you may need to change your type to "custom" AND you cant use a `payment_method` see [Create a card token](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card)

Answer (score 1):

You would tokenize a debit card using Stripe.js and Elements [0], then attach it to the Connect account as an external account: stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_cards/create

[0] stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement

Comment: I can create a token for the card from `response.setupIntent.payment_method` from `this.props.stripe.confirmCardSetup(...)` but how do I work it into the `stripe.accounts.create`?

Comment: You pass the token in the `external_account` field on Account create: https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create?lang=python#create_account-external_account